# Woocommerce open single product tab on button click

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

On my single product page I have button where I want to open default product tab named "description" on click on specific button with `id="cely-popis"`. This should perform only when another tab is active than "decription".

```
$("#cely-popis").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#tab-description").offset().top - 64
    }, 2000);

    $('.nav-link[href=tab-description]').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$('#cely-popis').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // smooth scroll to section
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#tabs-container').offset().top - 32
    }, 2000);

    // add "active" class
    $('.wc-tabs li a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    }); 

    $('.wc-tabs li#tab-title-description a').addClass('active');
    $('#tab-description').addClass('active');
    $('.woocommerce-Tabs-panel').css('display', 'none');
    $('#tab-description').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the description tab link using this line.

```
$('a[href="#tab-description"]').trigger('click')
```